# R: purrr: Paying the %.%er: Is walk passing entire piped vector, rather than elements?

Tags: r, iterator, pipe, tidyverse, purrr

Here is a function to take a file name stem, assemble the file name from path, stem, and suffix, read the file, drop a variable, and save the file again. In this simplified version the read stem and the save stem are the same, and I remove just one variable.

```
library(tidyverse)

strip_cps <-  function(X, path = path){
  readRDS(paste0(path = path, X, ".RDS")) %>%
    select(-"YEAR")  %>%
    saveRDS(file = paste0(path = path, X, ".RDS"))
}
```

Here is a function to call the previous function repeatedly, once per stem.

```
compact_cps <- function(stems, path){
  stems %>% 
    walk(strip_cps0(., path=path))
}
```

Here is a microscopic version of my data. Replace the data directory with a directory on your own system

```
df1 <- tibble(YEAR = 1, SEX = 1)
df2 = df1[1,] + c(1, 1)

saveRDS(df1, file = paste0("./CPS_1962-2018/", "df1", ".RDS"))
saveRDS(df2, file = paste0("./CPS_1962-2018/", "df2", ".RDS"))
```

Running the foregoing code on this data gets me the following error:

```
Error in gzfile(file, "rb") : invalid 'description' argument
```

From the traceback, I learn that `gzfile`  is called by `readRDS`. Rerunning the code with `debug`, I learn that the description argument of gzfile is

```
chr{1:2]  "./CPS_1962-2018/df1.RDS"   "./CPS_1962-2018/df1.RDS"
```

which is to say, a length-2 character vector.

Now, it seems to be a characteristic of bugs in my code that I can not resolve myself that they are not where I think they are. But it appears to me that walk, having received the character vector `stems = c(“df1”, ”df2”)` as its principle argument via `%>%` from the calling function `compact_cps`, then hands the whole vector to `strip_cps` instead of handing it one element at a time.

It seems more likely that I am missing something than that walk would do that, but I can't see what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
compact_cps <- function(stems, path){
  stems %>% 
    walk(strip_cps, path=path))
}
```

the first argument to walk is the vector stems, the next argument is the name of the function you want to call for each element in the vector, then any additional arguments to the function.

Comment: Thanks Adam! That did the job. I would have sworn up and down that that was the first thing I tried. Apparently there was something broken in strip_cps which I subsequently fixed, and then didn't get back to this version of compact_cps. Someday I'd like to be a good enough programmer to make mistakes by which I am not embarrassed.